# how can i keep track of localStorage with useState, React

Tags: reactjs

Im trying to keep track of `localStorage` with `useState` but every time I try to `setState(localStorage)` it dont do anything because it is already setted to `localStorage`, but the problem is, when I add some item to `localStorage`, the `state` is not updated, and I cant `setState(localStorage)` again. What can I do to my `State` update as `localStorage` updates?

Also tried this, but same problem:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setStorage(localStorage)
}, [localStorage]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To force a re-render without actually changing the state we need to create a new stance of the same element `setStorage({ ...localStorage});`. This works for my problem